# BlogEngine.net - how do I export my blog?

Tags: migrate-data, blogengine.net

I can't seem to find Export in my settings anymore.  It used to be in the Admin dashboard under *Settings -> Import & Export* but it is not showing up anymore.  What am I missing?

version 3.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem on version 3.2.0.3 and found your post while searching for a solution.

Turns out the option is still there, but the advanced settings page is just hidden - for some reason!

To find the import/export options, go directly to `http://www.example.com/blog/admin/#/settings/advanced` and scroll down to the bottom of the screen.

It should look like this:

[image]

(I found the hint for this by [searching the source for 'export'](https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=export))